# How can I get current day OHLCV hourly dta from the Coin Market Cap API?

Tags: cryptoapi, cryptocurrency, coinmarketcap

I recently started using the Coin Market Cap API. It has 2 main endpoints that I have been using OHLCV historical and OHLCV Latest. The historical API allows for hourly data but not including data for the current day. The other endpoint gives you the data of the day but not hourly. Is it possible to get hourly data from the current day?

Answer (score 0):

The OHLCV latest is reserved for Paid plans.
The endpoint is not available for basic(free) or hobbyist(29/month),
You will need a plan startup(79/month) or above.

Now, if you have the correct plan, you can use the
endpoint: `/v2/cryptocurrency/ohlcv/latest`
more details here [OHLCV v2](https://coinmarketcap.com/api/documentation/v1/#operation/getV2CryptocurrencyOhlcvLatest).

```
https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/cryptocurrency/ohlcv/latest
```

**The information in this endpoint is updated every *10 minutes***

The string query parameters are:

- `id` => string:  One or more comma-separated cryptocurrency CoinMarketCap IDs. Example: 1,2
- `symbol` => string: (Alternatively) pass one or more comma-separated cryptocurrency symbols. Example: "BTC,ETH".

at least one of the above is needed for a successful call

- `convert` => string: (optional) calculate price in fiat currencies supported by CMC
- `convert_id`  => string: similar above but using CMC IDs